# NavBar style "leaking" to my welcome page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jakarta-ee, materialize

I have a navBar that looks like this:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/css/materialize.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <a href="#" class="brand-logo">UNDO</a>
                <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <li><a href="#">Clientes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Productos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pedidos</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <script src="Resources/js/materialize.js"></script>
        <script src="Resources/js/jquery.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which is included in my welcome page that only has an `h1` tag and no css:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@include file="navBar.jsp"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is my welcome page</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Yet the font size and family of that `h1` is changed when I include the navBar file. I don't mind it to be honest but I feel like it shouldn't work that way and I want to understand what im doing. Is it because of the way I implemented the css and js files? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Uncommented the include line to avoid confusion.

Thanks!

Comment: Your navBar jsp should not include the DOCTYPE, <html>, <head>, or <body> tags. You're importing those into a page that already has those tags, so it will be included twice on the page. This is probably not a fix for your issue, but may help.

Comment: Also the include should be placed within the <body> tag on your welcome page instead of outside of the <html> tag.

Comment: You'd might want to share a live example of your code but it seems like your issue arise from the materialize.css file. It is included in the main page. Materialize css changes h1. Do you get the following change: h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
} ?

Comment: @EricBellDesigns thanks for the tips, they were really helpful. And yes, the issue persists, sadly.

Comment: No problem. Ok, let's do this... comment out the include, then inspect the h1 tag via Web Inspector. See what rules are being applied to the h1 tag. Then add the include back in, and do the same thing. You should see a change in the h1 rule that should help narrow down where the change is coming from.

Comment: The css file should also be placed in your welcome page and not within the navBar.jsp. I think @yccteam is right about the css file changing the h1.

Comment: @EricBellDesigns I think he is. If i comment the include, the h1 has a font-size of 2em and margins of 0.67em. With the include, it has a different font family, a font-size of 4.2rem and margins of 2.8rem 0 1.68rem 0. But if i place the css in the welcome page, the h1 style will still change. What should i do if i want materialize to style the navbar and not the welcome page?

Comment: @yccteam You are right. What should i do if i want the css to affect the navbar but leave the welcome page unchanged?

Comment: You'd need to use WebPack or something to apply an entire css file only to a section/module without it affecting the rest of the page. You should probably rewrite the materialize css file to apply only to elements within the navBar.jsp. Are you depending on materialize.css to style many elements?

Comment: I've never used JSP, but you could try to encapsulate your nav bar as a web component with a shadow dom (check browser compatibility to see if this solution is valid for you).
Another thing - you can add the main page styles at the bottom of the page, so that its styles will take precedence on the included styles at the top.  This might affect the styles of the included navBar though...

Comment: @EricBellDesigns im planning on using materialize for the whole project. I just wanted to understand what was going on and wanted to know if i was doing it correctly.So, if im planning on using the same file in several pages that will consume the same css, the css import should be done in the pages and not the included file?

Comment: If you need materialize.css to apply to many elements, I would suggest including that on your master page, then write specific CSS to override materialize.css for elements you wish to customize. If materialize.css is only applied to a few elements, I would remove it and add only the css rules you need to your main css file. Hope that helps.

Comment: @yccteam I will look into it. Im still going to use Materialize for the whole project, my question was entirely for educational purposes, i wanted to understand what was going on. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @EricBellDesigns Of course that helps. You were really helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help. Feel free to reach out if you have any other problems. I've been working with jsp pages for about 4 years